# Not sure how to capture the results of this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have the following query I'm executing against a remote SQL Server:

```
EXEC LinkedServer.MyDatabase..sp_executesql N'SELECT sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(''dbo_td_coater_rga_new'');';
```

The query works fine, but I'm not sure how to capture the results of the query and stored it to a variable. For example, this does not work:

```
Declare @begin_lsn binary(10)

Set @begin_lsn = EXEC LinkedServer.MyDatabase..sp_executesql N'SELECT sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(''dbo_td_coater_rga_new'');';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the variable to `sp_executesql`. You have to declare it as `OUTPUT` to receive the value back:

```
Declare @begin_lsn binary(10)

EXEC LinkedServer.MyDatabase..sp_executesql N'SELECT @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(''dbo_td_coater_rga_new'');', 
    N'@begin_lsn binary(10) OUTPUT', @begin_lsn OUTPUT
```